# How do I dynamically allocate 2D array using user input

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, clang, scanf

I'm trying to correct some clang errors that I'm getting when opening my C code with emacs  and when checking the compiled code with valgrind. I have made this code to answer a puzzle from CodinGame. To be clear, all of the tests from the website succeeded and the code doesn't produce errors when using suggested inputs but I want to remove these clang errors so there's no problem with memory. The problem is that I'm using mallocs to define a 2D string array using dimensions from user inputs and I then need to fill this array from user input.

What the code does is that it takes a diagram like this as the input :

```
7 7
A  B  C
|  |  |
|--|  |
|  |--|
|  |--|
|  |  |
1  2  3
```

Then, for each column, it follows it and switches columns when he meets a connection (represented by `-` here). It eventually displays the pairs made with this method. Using the example from above, it displays this :

```
A2
B1
C3
```

This is the code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main()
{
    int W, H;
    scanf("%d%d", &W, &H); fgetc(stdin);

    char** tab = malloc(H * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < H; ++i)
    {
      tab[i] = malloc((W+1) * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%[^\n]", tab[i]); fgetc(stdin);
    }

    int currT;
    int ligne;
    int currCol;

    for (currT = 0; currT < W; currT+=3)
    {
        currCol = currT;

        for (ligne = 1; ligne < H-1; ++ligne)
        {
            if (currCol != W-1 && tab[ligne][currCol+1] == '-')
            {
                currCol += 3;
            }
            else if (currCol != 0 && tab[ligne][currCol-1] == '-')
            {
                currCol += -3;
            }
        }
        printf("%c%c\n", tab[0][currT], tab[H-1][currCol]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < H; ++i)
    {
    free(tab[i]);
    }

    free(tab);

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the *core.NullDereference* error from these two lines :

```
if (currCol != W-1 && tab[ligne][currCol+1] == '-')
```

```
printf("%c%c\n", tab[0][currT], tab[H-1][currCol]);
```

Comment: `W+1 * sizeof(char)` should be `(W+1)*sizeof(char)` because `*` has higher precedence than `+`. It won't actually make a difference here, since `sizeof(char)` is `1`. But it would be needed for other types.

Comment: `currcol += 3` and `currCol += -3` can cause `currCol` to go out of bounds. I'm not sure how that can cause an error about dereferencing a null pointer, but it's definitely undefined behavior.

Comment: BTW, `+= -3` would usually be written `-= 3`

Comment: @AndreasWenzel sorry i'll edit it rn

Comment: thanks a lot @Barmar i'll edit these now and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Editing the `malloc()` and `+=` won't make a difference. You need to fix the logic of how you use `currCol`. I don't know what this code is trying to do, so I can't provide any specific guidance there.